# Woocommerce - Bcc email only when the admin is recipient OR by Order Status

Tags: wordpress, email, woocommerce

How to Get email recipient to make an conditional function to add extra bcc email header on email only to admin OR by Order Status?

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_headers', 'profit_extra_email', 10, 2);
function profit_extra_email( $headers ) {
    $headers .= 'BCC: Vendas Promocional Fitness <eu@site.com>' . "\r\n";
    return $headers;
}
```

This function above work, but bcc email retrieve all emails. I need retrieve only emails to admin OR by Order Status.

Help any!! :O

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 variables passed to the [`woocommerce_email_headers`](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/emails/class-wc-email.php#L292) filter. Since none of them appear to be the `$in_admin` variable that is passed to templates, we have to take a different approach. The second param is `$email_id` which is a unique identifier for each email class. Therefore we can make an array of all the admin emails and check if the current email is in that array. If so, add your CC.

```
function so_31737121_email_headers( $headers, $email_id, $order ){
    $admin_emails = array( 
        'low_stock',
        'no_stock',
        'backorder',
        'cancelled_order',
        'new_order'
    );

    if( in_array( $email_id, $admin_emails ) ){
        $headers .= 'BCC: Vendas Promocional Fitness <eu@site.com>' . "\r\n";
    }
    return $headers;
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_headers', 'so_31737121_email_headers', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Nice Helga! It looks like it will work now, but I'm worried Order_status customized I'm using. You know what I need to include them?

Comment: If you only modified the template it shouldn't matter.

Comment: Oh No! Partial Works... Woks fine only when email fo to botth "Customer and Admin'. Email only admin not trigger to BCC. :(

Comment: In conditional line  `if( in_array( $email_id, $admin_emails ) || ( get_option('admin_email') == $wc_recipient?????? ) ){ ` i think include a comparative with wp admin email and the recipient of wc email.

Any Suggestion?

Comment: Which emails are sent to both customer and admin? From what I can tell in the email classes none of the default emails are configured that way.

Comment: In truth it is not working. because bcc_email was just getting the same admin and customer emails because I was testing it as a client.
What I really need is to get the recipient of the WC and email where this is equal to WP ADMIN, BCC email is returned.

Comment: i'm using a plugin called WooCommerce Custom Order Status & Actions.

Comment: and this plugin does not generate or use the actions within the `$admin_emails = array(' ')`. He has only generates order_status. @helgatheviking, It is how to set order_status rather than order actions?

Comment: I don't have the custom plugin so I'm not familiar with it. Emails should all have IDs (see [example](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/emails/class-wc-email-new-order.php#L27)) or [here](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-wc-emails.php#L400). You will need to find the appropriate IDs. Btw, I believe order status is in the order object: `$order->order_status`. PS- please edit your question with all this extra information and next time consider including that from the start. I have actually answered the question as posted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84847/discussion-between-adson-cicilioti-and-helgatheviking).