# How to get WooCommerce email recipient?

Tags: wordpress, email, woocommerce

How to get recipient of the woocommerce emails for $wc_recipient var in this code?

```
function profit_extra_email( $headers ){

  if(  get_option('admin_email') == $wc_recipient  ){

    $headers .= 'BCC: bcc@email.com>' . '\r\n';

  }

  return $headers;

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_headers', 'profit_extra_email', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: He's trying to resolve this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31737121/383847). It is definitely different, but I'm not sure it is needed yet to resolve the original question of adding BCC recipients on admin emails.

Comment: @mevius, I need send bcc email only when admin is recipient.

Comment: Yes @helgatheviking. This is an sub-question.

Comment: 'woocommerce_email_headers' is a filter and not a action hook!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the wp_mail filter?
Add this to your functions.php

```
function my_wp_mail_filter( $mail ) {
    if( $mail['to'] == get_option('admin_email') )
        $mail['headers'] .= 'BCC: bcc@email.com>' . '\r\n';

    return $mail;
}
add_filter( 'wp_mail', 'my_wp_mail_filter' );
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
function profit_extra_email( $headers, $recipient ){
if(  get_option('admin_email') == $recipient  ){
$headers .= 'BCC: bcc@email.com>' . '\r\n';
}

return $headers;
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_headers', 'profit_extra_email', 10, 2 );
```

$recipient is available in woocommerce functions, I haven't try it but it should work

Comment: woocommerce_email_headers has now three arguments
http://hookr.io/filters/woocommerce_email_headers/

so must be `add_action( 'woocommerce_email_headers', 'profit_extra_email', 10, 3);`

Comment: 'woocommerce_email_headers' is a filter and not a action hook!